# React-Native NativeModules.AudioRecorderManager not exist

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm using React-Native `0.69.0`.
In my app, I'm using `NativeModules` like this :

```
import ReactNative, {
  NativeModules,
} from "react-native";
```

and I need it like that :
`var AudioRecorderManager = NativeModules.AudioRecorderManager;`

For some reasons, `AudioRecorderManager` is available in `NativeModules` with Android, but not with iOS.
So, my iOS app can't launch some components.

Comment: have you installed pods before running app on ios ?

Comment: Yes; absolutely

Comment: Okay then you may check these
- Make sure audio library which you are using has module or folder of ios (if it not then library is only for android)
- Make sure audio library which you are using is installed by pods (by checking terminal with "Installing audiolib pod" log)
- clear and reinstall pods